# Extending (inherit) entity framwork class (not using partial)

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, entity-framework-4, extend

**How it started?**

I wanted to add two columns, that are not in business objec collection into radGridView. Specifically NewUrl anad NewIdOnFilehost. :)

**So what i tried to do?**

I put this into grid

```
radGridViewReuploadStatus.ItemsSource = FileHostings.Filesonic.getdAllDeletedLinks();
```

Then i added them new columns

```
<telerik:GridViewColumn Header="New F.H.Id" UniqueName="NewFilehostId" Width="*"></telerik:GridViewColumn>
                <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="New URL" UniqueName="NewUrl" Width="*"></telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

**So what is problem?**

radGridViewReuploadStatus.Rows does not exists.
I don't know why they did not added it to wpf radGridView, it is in its aspx version. I was able to get rows using getChildsOfType, but this is obviously not ideal way.

**What i did next?**

```
class dlExtended : DownloadLink {
        public string NewUrl { get; set; }
        public string NewIdOnFilehost { get; set; }
    }
```

**Finally the PROBLEM - what basic i don't understand**

How do i make dlExtended from DownloadLink? (i know it is wrong name convention, it is just for example :) )
And how do i make list of dlExtended from collection of DownloadLink? There must be better way then using foreach!

**Now i'm probably doing it wrong**

So now i should do constructor and set EACH property of dlExneded according to one passed in passed DownloadLink?!

Well maybe it is doable by reflection LIKE this

```
public DownloadLinkExtended(DownloadLink origDl){
        PropertyInfo[] myObjectProperties = origDl.GetType().GetProperties(); //BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in myObjectProperties)
        {
            if (pi.GetValue(origDl, null) != null)
            {
                pi.SetValue(this, pi.GetValue(origDl, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Well this is stupid. **So what i don't get about extending the class and adding new properties to it?**

I know that EF4 classes are partial and i can add properties to them simply via partial class, but i want these only for the grid and not anywhere else.

Comment: Formulation of one probable solution:
How to inherit class, so that constructor with parameter instance of parent class would set all inherited properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My "Shallow" object copier is very similar to yours, but the null test is subtly different. It also has a handy extension method wrapper - so it will need to be in a static class.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy an object to destination object, only matching fields will be copied
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="sourceObject">An object with matching fields of the destination object</param>
    /// <param name="destObject">Destination object, must already be created</param>
    public static void ShallowCopyTo<T>(this object sourceObject, ref T destObject)
    {
        Copy<T>(sourceObject,ref destObject);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy an object to destination object, only matching fields will be copied
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="sourceObject">An object with matching fields of the destination object</param>
    /// <param name="destObject">Destination object, must already be created</param>
    public static void Copy<T>(object sourceObject, ref T destObject)
    {
        //  If either the source, or destination is null, return
        if (sourceObject == null || destObject == null)
            return;

        //  Get the type of each object
        Type sourceType = sourceObject.GetType();
        Type targetType = destObject.GetType();

        //  Loop through the source properties
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in sourceType.GetProperties())
        {
            //  Get the matching property in the destination object
            PropertyInfo targetObj = targetType.GetProperty(p.Name);
            //  If there is none, skip
            if (targetObj == null)
                continue;

            //  Set the value in the destination
            targetObj.SetValue(destObject, p.GetValue(sourceObject, null), null);
        }
    }
```

However, I also have a deep copier, but this only works with serializable objects, so look into the code generation you use from the EDMX, I don't think it will work with the EF classes directly, but does with the POCO generated classes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Reference Article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx
/// 
/// Provides a method for performing a deep copy of an object.
/// Binary Serialization is used to perform the copy.
/// </summary>

public static class ObjectCopier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Perform a deep Copy of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
    /// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
        }

        // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are EF classes (not POCO from the T4 templates) then you may not want to inherit from them anyway - because you end up with the the EF baggage. That aside I think there are a number of potential solutions.

If its only used in one place, you can improve on the for loop with projection in Linq

```
var newthings = oldlinks.Select(old => new dlExtended{ NewUrl =old.NewUrl , NewIdOnFilehost =old.NewIdOnFilehost });
```

you can also write a constructor for dlExtended that takes a DownloadLink and then do

```
var newthings = oldlinks.Select(old => new dlExtended(old));
```

which puts the property copying in one place.

you can also build a generic extension method to copy properties with the same name between two objects and use that in a variety of ways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Your fist approach would be nice, but i would like to use this new class on more then one place.

Uith your second approach i would still need to specify each property like 

     this.property1=orig.property1;
                    this.property2=orig.property2;
                    this.property3=orig.property3; 
     
Is taht right? That is exctly what i don't want to. 

"extension method to copy propertiess with the same name between two objects " is actually thing i'm having problem, because my attempt using don't handle properties that are other EF classes.

Comment: Anyway after quick google i think that POCO you mention, more specifically this http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313 and using it as somthing like ModelView in MVVM can be the sollution i'm seeking, but well - i heard about poco for the first time here so it will take time studing :/ and i still wonder how to that reflection right.

Comment: I think its rare to end up passing an EF class into a view. It works, all the examples do it, but in practice nearly all real world scenarios tend to need a POCO Viewmodel - a class that represents the data required for a view. Keeping these in sync when the DB changes is one issue, performance with instantiating huge numbers is another. Re the copying, I'll post another answer with my object copy code just incase it helps.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that you really understand what question is and what issues i'm trying to solve. This not actual real world application, it is more for learning purposes. Do you know of any guide with best practices/automatization of keeping viewmodels in sync with dbb?

Comment: I probably have no idea what you are doing :-) But I do know what I've done, and what I've been advised as I learn. I also use the Telerik controls (mostly MVC) and know that if any JSON serialization is involved it gets "interesting" with raw EF classes.  Also binding posts to EF models (in MVC at least) is v dangerous as any data posted that matches a property is bound by default. Anyway, syncing viewmodels - add to this if you find anything better than what I posted :-)